# Web scraping CNBC US Treasury page

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape the CNBC US Treasury yields table https://www.cnbc.com/us-treasurys/ but not getting anywhere. Here's my code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url='https://www.cnbc.com/us-treasurys/'
headers =  {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT x.y; Win64; x64; rv:10.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/10.0 '}
page=requests.get(url,headers=headers)
soup=BeautifulSoup(page.content,'lxml')
print('Page status code',page.status_code)
#
output=[]
mydata=soup.find_all('td',class_="BasicTable-unchanged BasicTable-numData")
for tag in mydata:
    output.append(tag.text.strip())
print(output)
```

It doesn't produce any output even though I've carefully inspected the page using Google Chrome. Similar code for the individual quote pages such as https://www.cnbc.com/quotes/US6M works fine but it's too slow to loop through all 11 maturities. I'd like to scrape the entire table at once for speed. Any thoughts how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

The data you see on the page is loaded dynamically via JavaScript. You can simulate the Ajax request with `requests` module. For example:

```py
import json
import requests

url = "https://quote.cnbc.com/quote-html-webservice/quote.htm"

params = {
    "noform": "1",
    "partnerId": "2",
    "fund": "1",
    "exthrs": "0",
    "output": "json",
    "symbolType": "issue",
    "symbols": "5093148|5093149|5093150|15183113|5093151|5093158|5093159|19892965|5093160|135058359|5093168",
    "requestMethod": "extended",
}

data = requests.get(url, params=params).json()

# uncomment this to print all data:
# print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))

for q in data["ExtendedQuoteResult"]["ExtendedQuote"]:
    print(
        "{:<8} {:>8} {:>8}".format(
            q["QuickQuote"]["symbol"],
            q["QuickQuote"]["last"],
            q["QuickQuote"]["change"],
        )
    )
```

Prints:

```
US1M        0.053    0.002
US3M        0.053     0.00
US6M        0.053     0.00
US1Y        0.066     0.00
US2Y         0.22   -0.002
US3Y        0.403   -0.008
US5Y         0.79   -0.019
US7Y        1.096   -0.036
US10Y        1.32    -0.05
US20Y       1.865   -0.061
US30Y       1.938   -0.065
```

Comment: That runs very quickly! Many thanks for your insight on JavaScript.

Comment: Hi Andrej, I've been using this code a lot but now would like to access additional data. How did you figure out the symbols, such as "5093148" for each displayed data element? SteveB